# Creating multidimension associative array in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new in Php MySql and a lot of answer in this question but I still having an error in this. So what I'm trying to do is to loop my array and to create a multidimensional associative array.

I have evaluation_details, category, segment and question tables
In evaluation_details, I have the the id of category, subcategory, segment and question  tables

And in category I have column is_cat and its data type is tiny int the value is either 0 or 1 which means 1 if the given category is the main category and 0 if it is sub category, so I need to create an array like this.

Inside Category a multiple subcategory and each subcategory has one question. And each category can group by segment.

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "id" => 2
    "title" => "second evaluation form"
    "emp_position" => "System Architecture"
    "first_segment_name" => array:2 [
      0 => {
        +"category_name" => array 2 [
            0 => {
                +"subcategory" => sub_1
                +"question" => question_1
            },

            1 => {
                +"subcategory" => sub_2
                +"question" => question_2
            }
        ]
      }

      1 => {
        +"category_name" => array 2 [
            0 => {
                +"subcategory" => sub_3
                +"question" => question_3
            },

            1 => {
                +"subcategory" => sub_4
                +"question" => question_4
            }
        ]
      }

    ]

    "second_segment_name" => array:2 [
      0 => {
        +"category_name" => array 3 [
            0 => {
                +"subcategory" => sub_5
                +"question" => question_5
            },

            1 => {
                +"subcategory" => sub_6
                +"question" => question_6
            }

            2 => {
                +"subcategory" => sub_7
                +"question" => question_7
            }
        ]
      }

    ]
  ]

]
```

**And this is what I'm trying to do**

```
public function getEvaluation($data){

    $query = DB::table(
        DB::raw("(

                SELECT 
                e.id, 
                e.title,
                p.name position,
                s.name segment
                FROM 
                evaluation_details e_d
                JOIN evaluation e ON e_d.evaluation_id = e.id
                JOIN segment s ON e_d.segment_id = s.id
                JOIN position p ON e.position_id = p.id
                WHERE e.position_id = 2
                ORDER BY segment

        ) As `a`
        ")
    )->get()->toArray();

    $query = json_decode(json_encode($query), true);


    foreach ($query as $index => $data) {
       $first_array[$index]['id'] = $data['id'];
       $first_array[$index]['title'] = $data['title'];
       $first_array[$index]['emp_position'] = $data['position'];

       $first_array[$index]['segments'] = DB::table('evaluation_details AS e_d')
            ->select('c.name AS category')
            ->join('category AS c', 'e_d.category_id', 'c.id')
            ->join('evaluation As e', 'e_d.evaluation_id', '=', 'e.id')
            ->join('segment AS s', 'e_d.segment_id', 's.id')
            ->where('e.position_id', '=', '2')
            ->get()->toArray();   

    }
    echo '<pre>';
    dd($first_array);exit;


}
```

* But it gives me different result I need to have another array inside category *

```
    array:2 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "id" => 2
    "title" => "first evaluation form"
    "emp_position" => "System Architecture"
    "segments" => array:2 [
      0 => {#497
        +"category": "test"
      }
      1 => {#498
        +"category": "Quality & Dependibility"
      }
    ]
  ]

]
```

I hope anyone can help me with this.

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I'm confuse. what is the code you posted? Do you want this to convert to multidimensional array? or do you want to create multi dimensional array just like this?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz  i want to create an array like that

Comment: Please check the question asked by @Bluetree

Comment: @Bluetree hi, i just want to create an array like that. I mentioned the table above

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I just need to loop the table that I mentioned to create an array like that

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is the exactly result from your query? can you please post it also?

Comment: The result from this tables. category, subcategory, segment and question. vardump them and post it here

Comment: @Bluetree i updated my post from above, kindly check it

Comment: Please try my answer. And tell me if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To to this we need to delete the `category` key and replace the key with its `category name`.

Add this at the end inside your foreach loop.

```
foreach( $first_array[$index]['segments'] as $index2 => $segment){
    $category_name = $segment['category']; //This will output test and resplace the category key
    $first_array[$index]['segments'][$index2][$category_name] = DB::Table...;//Perform your subcategory query here just like what you did in segment.
    unset($first_array[$index]['segments'][$index2]['category']);//Delete the old
}
```

**Change your code from this:**

```
foreach ($query as $index => $data) {
       $first_array[$index]['id'] = $data['id'];
       $first_array[$index]['title'] = $data['title'];
       $first_array[$index]['emp_position'] = $data['position'];

       $first_array[$index]['segments'] = DB::table('evaluation_details AS e_d')
            ->select('c.name AS category')
            ->join('category AS c', 'e_d.category_id', 'c.id')
            ->join('evaluation As e', 'e_d.evaluation_id', '=', 'e.id')
            ->join('segment AS s', 'e_d.segment_id', 's.id')
            ->where('e.position_id', '=', '2')
            ->get()->toArray();   

    }
```

**To this**

```
foreach ($query as $index => $data) {
   $first_array[$index]['id'] = $data['id'];
   $first_array[$index]['title'] = $data['title'];
   $first_array[$index]['emp_position'] = $data['position'];

   $first_array[$index]['segments'] = DB::table('evaluation_details AS e_d')
        ->select('c.name AS category')
        ->join('category AS c', 'e_d.category_id', 'c.id')
        ->join('evaluation As e', 'e_d.evaluation_id', '=', 'e.id')
        ->join('segment AS s', 'e_d.segment_id', 's.id')
        ->where('e.position_id', '=', '2')
        ->get()->toArray();   
    foreach( $first_array[$index]['segments'] as $index2 => $segment){
        $category_name = $segment['category']; //This will output test and resplace the category key
        $first_array[$index]['segments'][$index2][$category_name] = DB::Table...;//Perform your subcategory query here just like what you did in segment.
        unset($first_array[$index]['segments'][$index2]['category']);//Delete the old
    }
}
```

Comment: its because you helped me :)))